# Modify PHP Post Data

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post, trim

I am using a swipe card to capture id and use that to store attendance into the database. I have a form with jQuery that automatically submits the form when a user enter 8 character string into the input field. I want to use the data from the swipe card to do this but when I swipe my card the output I get is `;910522804?` where it should be `k1052280`.

How could I trim the data so when someone swipes their card it should get rid of `; ? and the last digit`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The Form and jQuery code is this

```
<form id="SwipeForm" action="Swiped.php" method="post">
    <input id="Swipe" name="studentID" type="text" value="" />&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
$(function () {
    $('#Swipe').bind('DOMAttrModified textInput input change keyup keypress paste', function() {
        var vallength = $(this).val().length;

        if (vallength == 8) {
            $('#SwipeForm').submit();
        }
    });
});
</script>

<form id="SwipeForm" action="Swiped.php" method="post">
    <input id="Swipe" name="studentID" type="text" value="" />&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative you can use the strlen function with substr to get the part of your string.

```
$str = ';910522804?';
$str = substr($str, 1, strlen($str) - 2);
var_dump($str);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for quick reply, this is very useful, now all I have to do is attach the 'k' and it will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the first character and the last two characters, nested `substr` functions work:

```
$str = ';910522804?';
$str = substr(substr($str, 1), 0, -2);
echo $str;
// 91052280
```

Comment: Thank you I will be combining both answers to solve my problem